# Firebase: failed to bounce to type when getting list

Tags: java, android

I get the

```
com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to bounce to type
```

error when trying to cast the following data into a User class.

```
users
    userkey
        name: "myName"
        list1
            0: "Apple"
            0: "Orange"
        list2:
            "a":"aValue"
            "b":"bValue"
```

The user class looks like:

```
String name;
List<String> list1;
List<String> list2;

public User() {}
...
// setters and getters for fields.
```

Am I casting to the wrong types? Or is it not possible to retrieve the lists?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make a list of **object** type. Don't do like this. Change your **list1** and **list2** types to some object. Hint given below:

```
public class UserObject{
  private String key;
  private String value;

  // initiaize getter setter and member function :)
}

List<UserObject> list1;

UserObject userObj =  new UserObject("a","aValue");
list1.add(userObj);
```

If you'r trting to save this kind of data i.e: key-value pair then it's better to use [Hashmap](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/hashmap-in-java-with-example/) instead.

Comment: I tried making them Hashmap<Integer,String> and Hashmap<String,String> but still didn't work.